# How to check max number of file open-wirte-close operations per second in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, ofstream, limits

Having some files on disk. The files have fixed size lines with the following format:

> 98969547,1236548896,1236547899,0a234505,1478889565

which `0a234505` is an IP Address in hex format.

I should open a file, read on line of the file and found the IP address. Then, create a directory on disk (if not exists) with the same name as IP Address and create a file witch holds the line under that directory.
The file name is today date e.g. 2017-02-09. If the directory and the and its file is created previously, simply append the corresponding line to the end of the file.

My files contains too much lines e.g. 100000 or greater, so this steps must be repeated for all lines.
My requirement is to process one files with 100000 lines in one second.

so what i need to understand is what is the maximum number of file open-wirte-close operations per second in ubuntu 16.04?

if the answer does not satisfy my requirement, How should I properly do this?

so its better to say if the OS limitation does not allow me to do such a huge amount of open-write-close operations, is there any second way to do this?

> Programming language: c++
>
> OS: ubuntu-16.04 4.4.0-62-generic

Comment: Yes, that is my problem too ...

Comment: Ubuntu itself does not have any such limit. The storage device on which the filesystem lives may have something to say about how many IO operations per second it can do. Have you tried just writing the straightforward program and then measuring its performance?

Comment: @AlexP Yes i do. the best write rate was 6000 records per second but i need to know how much this measurement is real!

Comment: 6000 per second sound about right for a desktop consumer-grade 3.5 inch hard disk. Do it again with an SSD, then do it again with an enterprise-grade all-SSD storage array ([example](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/storage/3par.html)).